# Error while using h2o.init() in R - Java related

Tags: java, r, rstudio, h2o

I am getting this error while initializing h2o

h2o.init()
H2O is not running yet, starting it now...

```
Error in .h2o.startJar(ip = ip, port = port, name = name, nthreads = nthreads,  : 
  Your java is not supported: java version "1.7.0_80"
Please download the latest Java SE JDK from the following URL:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
```

I have tried installing latest version of Java, but still the problem persists. Kindly help.

Comment: Check your JAVA_HOME env variable.

Comment: Can you tell me how to check JAVA_HOME env variable ? And what exactly to look for ?

Comment: Changing JAVA_HOME env location helped. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

From error it clearly saying "**Your java is not supported:** java version "1.7.0_80""

Install new version of java from oracle [site](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) ex: java 8

then set that jre path from [PATH and CLASSPATH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

> Windows 7:
>    1. From the desktop, right click the Computer icon.
>    2. Choose Properties from the context menu.
>    3. Click the Advanced system settings link.
>    4. Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.
>    5. In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.